# Pipe from echo to gnuplot variable?

Tags: bash, pipe, gnuplot, echo

What I want:

```
echo {0..2} | gnuplot --persist -e "f='{OUTPUT FROM ECHO}'" myplot.plg 
0 1 2
```

FILE myplot.plg:

```
print f
#plot for [fi in f] fi.".dat" using 1 w l title sprintf(fi)
```

USE:

```
echo "python sim.py > "{0..2}".dat &" | bash -
echo "node sim.js > "{0..2}".dat &" | bash -
echo {0..2} | gnuplot --persist -e {Stack Overflow Magic?} myplot.plg
```

The goal would be to run many instances of this sim simultaneously (different initial conditions) using echo to create the command, & to fork the process, and bash to run it.  Once the simulation is complete, I want to display all of the plots in one figure.  Ex: plot {0..100}.dat nolegend

Comment: I don't think there's really a sane way to do that.  Last time I tried (many years ago) I think I ended up creating a here document for each run, and passing that as the script to Gnuplot, IIRC.

Comment: If you have Python anyway, Matplotlib is a lot more versatile if you just need basic plotting.

Comment: @tripleee: Have not used gnuplot before, but running a command substitution syntax inside one of the flags, `f` won't work here?

Comment: It's not specific to python, that's just an example use case.  I managed to make it work with xargs and I am satisfied with the elegance.

Answer (score 1):

Just when I thought all hope was lost, xargs to the rescue!

```
echo {0..2} | xargs -I{} gnuplot --persist -e "f='{}'" myplot.plg
```

More fun:

```
alias sgp="xargs -I{} gnuplot --persist -e \"f='{}'\""
echo {0..2} | sgp plot_files.plg
```

[Credit to this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kAB_VgokMY)

Edit:
Doesn't work in tcsh (alias sgp command).  xargs is also different.